# Laravel 9: how to manage size of completed job history?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Our Laravel 9 based app suite runs *lots* of little jobs for one feature, pretty much constantly. The `recent_jobs` and `completed_jobs` keys in Redis are rather large due to this - the apparent default of 7 days' history can consume 4GB or more of Redis memory, each. This is painful.

I recently was tasked with managing the Laravel environment, but I'm not deeply familiar with the Laravel platform. (So, apologies if I use the wrong terminology!)

I'd like to know whether there are built-in mechanisms (like, a config setting somewhere) to manage this particular detail more closely. All I've been able to find with web searches is information about managing the default job queue and failed job queue (there's *lots* about failed jobs!); but I can't find anything about managing the size of the completed jobs history.

Both of the Redis keys are apparently sorted sets with the sort key being the Unix epoch timestamp of the job. We're used to this model, we do the same thing. For the moment I am using Redis commands to manually remove set entries where the timestamp key is less than `(now - 48h)`. This works to manage Redis memory use but I don't know what that's doing to the Laravel job history management outside of those two Redis keys.

We apparently do not use Horizon. There are signs we explored it at some point in the past, but it's not currently active - I do not know why yet. If Horizon is the "correct" approach for this then we'll need to implement that for the long term, but if possible I'm looking for a lightweight immediate solution that doesn't involve installing or enabling any new packages.

The best solution IMO would be some way to decorate a particular job handler class with some flag saying "keeping a history of this job is not needed", so that history would not even be stored after job completion (something similar to the public `$timeout` property). The big offender here is a very lightweight job that transforms and stores small batches of status messages which are pretty constantly generated, and runs *lots* of one-batch instances; keeping a history of success of this job is not at all useful. (Rearchitecting it to persist and process many batches before exiting is too large a task for the immediate term. I need something simple and quick to implement to get Redis memory usage under control.)

Less attractive but still an improvement would be a config that sets how much completed job history to keep. If I can dial that down from 7 days to 48 hours then that will be sufficient for the moment. But I haven't been able to find any information on that possibility.

A `php artisan` command to prune the completed job history to *N* hours (something similar to `php artisan queue:prune-failed --hours=48`) would also be okay. I've been doing that manually with Redis commands to manage the history size; I'd much rather use something built into Laravel, if such exists, to ensure it's being done properly.

So: what is the "proper" way to manage completed job history size in Laravel?

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm not aware of a `completed_jobs` log outside of horizon, so I would suggest it might be good if you can find a file called 'horizon' anywhere in the system. If you can, it should contain some trimming properties, under the key 'trim' in an array. IIRC the values are in minutes for each, and I think the key you're looking for is `completed`

Comment: If that's not the case, I would recommend setting up a daily cron to purge these logs

Comment: If you have your job queue stored in Redis, look at the `{app_keyword}:completed_jobs` and `{app_keyword}:recent_jobs` keys.
As I said, Horizon is currently inactive in our environment.
If there is no artisan command to manage those keys, the cron job would be running the Redis commands I'm currently running to prune the content of those keys. I don't really want to automate that, I want to use a Laravel-native approach to manage them.

Comment: perhaps you could review this logic and extend it for completed jobs: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4ffac6f71467562dbe670f893af787bf5c610103/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/PruneFailedJobsCommand.php#L6

Comment: I'd really like to avoid doing coding changes that are essentially _extending Laravel_. I'm not at this point familiar enough with the full environment to do that comfortably or efficiently. I'm hoping there's just some existing base functionality (either in job class properties or job/queue management) that's not clearly documented so I'm missing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `trim.completed` Horizon config option. It defaults to 60 (minutes) and indicates the TTL for completed jobs.

[This](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/b14498a09af826035e46ae8d6b013d0ec849bdb7/src/Repositories/RedisJobRepository.php#L84) are the trim options you can set:

```
  $this->recentJobExpires = config('horizon.trim.recent', 60);
  $this->pendingJobExpires = config('horizon.trim.pending', 60);
  $this->completedJobExpires = config('horizon.trim.completed', 60);
  $this->failedJobExpires = config('horizon.trim.failed', 10080);
  $this->recentFailedJobExpires = config('horizon.trim.recent_failed', $this->failedJobExpires);
  $this->monitoredJobExpires = config('horizon.trim.monitored', 10080);
```

- https://github.com/laravel/horizon/pull/720
- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon#configuration

Comment: Except we're not using Horizon at the moment. Thanks for the info, if we do turn Horizon on I'll certainly investigate those configs.